# AzureMobile not inserting data

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I created an Azure Mobile App with SQL Server backend. Here's my code

```
    var userTable = request.azureMobile.tables('User');
    var item = {
        Username: postValues.Username,
        Password: postValues.Password,
        Email: postValues.Email,
        eth_account: web3.personal.newAccount(''),
        CreatedBy: CREATEDBY,
        usertypeid: DEFAULT_USER_TYPE,
        store_name: postValues.storename,
        address1: postValues.address,
        city: postValues.city,
        state: postValues.state,
        zipcode: postValues.zipcode || "",
        phone1: postValues.phone || ""
        // UpdatedBy: UPDATEDBY
        //PrivacyReceive: 'Just Friends',
        //PrivacyShare: 'Just Friends'
    };
    accounts.insert(item).then(function() {
         var userId = aud + ":" + item.id;

         //update our record with the user id
         item.UserId = userId;
         item.Token = jwthelper.zumoJwt(aud, userId, request.service.config.masterKey);
         accounts.update(item);

         // We don't want the salt or the password going back to the client
         delete item.Password;
         delete item.Salt;

         item.Status = "SUCCESS";
         item.Details = "User registered";
         response.status(201).send(item);
         });
```

When testing I couldn't get data inserted. I checked console log and this is what I've got:

```
- silly: Executing SQL statement INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([Username],[Password],[Email],[eth_account],[CreatedBy],[usertypeid],[store_name],[address1],[city],[state],[zipcode],[phone1],[Salt],[Token],[id]) VALUES (@Username,@Password,@Email,@eth_account,@CreatedBy,@usertypeid,@store_name,@address1,@city,@state,@zipcode,@phone1,@Salt,@Token,@id); SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE [id] = @id with parameters [{"name":"Username","value":"guoyangrui","type":{}},{"name":"Password","value":"kFZ/gcELIr7w7o4f/x8Z12lTfLxhlqyI4+9LpiynjBw=","type":{}},{"name":"Email","value":"guoyangrui@gmail.com","type":{}},{"name":"eth_account","value":"0x6957b6b2cf9aff94106a5a5ad49cdc6fb43f4521","type":{}},{"name":"CreatedBy","value":"Script","type":{}},{"name":"usertypeid","value":3},{"name":"store_name","value":"test store","type":{}},{"name":"address1","value":"test address","type":{}},{"name":"city","value":"test city","type":{}},{"name":"state","value":"test state","type":{}},{"name":"zipcode","value":"00000","type":{}},{"name":"phone1","value":"1234567890","type":{}},{"name":"Salt","value":"nj+WAmzA2EuheHeFvvx+34kgmpTUks54miqtwC8h5jY=","type":{}},{"name":"Token","value":"temp","type":{}},{"name":"id","value":"f5951ba5-f1e9-476b-b7b5-29fe8c3b5b6f","type":{"length":255}}]
```

There was no error message. However when I checked through Easy tables the data was not there. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this in a custom API or a table controller?  If you do a .catch() clause to trap the error, do you see an error?

Comment: Difficult to tell. If the INSERT is successfully executed, and there is no subsequent ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, it is being inserted into the database. Try connecting directly to the database using SSMS and see if the row is inserted. Use the MS_TableConnectionString value to connect.